# Spyder highlights my code and cannot see words

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Whenever I try to write some arguments to a function, spyder highlights it with white color, making me impossible to see anything that I write. My spyder version is 4.1.2 and Python 3.6.

I have re-started my computer and verified that the "Highlight" options in Tools>Preferences>Editor>Display are unchecked. The problem persists. I have attached a snapshop of the problem. It happens not only with the function os.path.join, but with any function I  complete with arguments.

[image: problem with code]

Comment: It’s also possible to change the colours / colour scheme used.  Have you tried this by chance?  (Also in preferences)

Comment: Yes, I changed the colors some time  ago and everything was working fine until this afternoon. I don't know why.